# Package system is broken. How to fix it?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I just recently bought an arduino and requires gcc-avr/avrdude to compile the software. I installed avr for another microprocessor component a while ago but is obviously an outdated version (gcc version 3.3 20030512 (prerelease)) so I went ahead to update these but it didn't work.

(Please note that before hand I also broke my aptdaemon through an incomplete wine installation (couldn't get passed font installation agreement) but I fixed that via a re-installation then accepting the agreement.)

I am trying to update these by running [bingo's build script](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=42631) but the dependencies it requires cannot be installed due to avr... terminal reports

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
libncurses5-dev is already the newest version.
libncurses5-dev set to manually installed.
libusb-0.1-4 is already the newest version.
libx11-dev is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
arduino-core : Depends: gcc-avr but it is not going to be installed
avr-libc : Depends: gcc-avr (>= 1:4.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: binutils-avr (>= 2.20) but it is not going to be installed
binutils-dev : Depends: binutils (= 2.21.0.20110327-2ubuntu3) but 2.21.0.20110327-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
libcwidget-dev : Depends: libcwidget3 (= 0.5.16-3ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libsigc++-2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libncursesw5-dev but it is not going to be installed
libmpfr-dev : Depends: libgmp3-dev (>= 4.2.dfsg-1) but it is not going to be installed
python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.1-0ubuntu5.1) but 2.7.1-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
Depends: python2.7-dev (>= 2.7.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
tk8.4-dev : Depends: tk8.4 (= 8.4.19-4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

But running

```
apt-get -f install
```

results in

```
(Reading database ... 163021 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking binutils-avr (from .../binutils-avr_2.20.1-1ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/binutils-avr_2.20.1-1ubuntu2_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/avr-size', which is also in package avr-binutils 2.13.90.030512-2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Unpacking gcc-avr (from .../gcc-avr_1%3a4.3.5-1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-avr_1%3a4.3.5-1_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/avr-g++', which is also in package avr-gcc-c++ 3.2.90.20030512-2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/binutils-avr_2.20.1-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-avr_1%3a4.3.5-1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried running update manager and updating my system via it but all I get is an error message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
arduino-core: Depends: gcc-avr but it is not installed
avr-libc: Depends: gcc-avr (>= 1:4.3.4) but it is not installed
Depends: binutils-avr (>= 2.20) but it is not installed
```

which then tells me to try running apt-get -f install which just results the same as last time.

So how can I fix my system, I really need the new avr, please :)
BTW, my system is Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Do you have synaptic installed in your system?!

Comment: Yes, why? I shouldn't have it?

Comment: Same error (but based on `libboost`). None of the answers worked for me.

Comment: The command `sudo apt --fix-broken install` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 88):

After you get that error, try `sudo apt-get -f install` to force an install of the files that didn't get loaded because of the error.

Then try `sudo apt-get update` again, `sudo apt-get -f install` back and forth until only the package that has the error is left.

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

and clean the cache

`sudo apt-get clean`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I found a solution just as you posted this :P I opened synaptic package manager and filtered out two broken packages which I then removed with SPM, which now everything runs sweet and smooth. Managed to install the dependencies and I am now installing avr using bingo's script! :) It's not finished yet but if it fails I will try your answer

Comment: good to hear its fixed

Comment: ok, Just deleted 11.04 partition and fresh installed 11.10. now running it alongside windows vista. So now I have the latest avr/binutils/libs etc installed. So I can now compile things for arduino :) yay!

Comment: As a result of this problem, I also failed to load mouse drivers and WLAN drivers. That means I have no more internet connection and can't use `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: doesn't work for me, `sudo apt-get -f install` also crashes

Comment: not working.... everytime i get same error E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: in my case, I had to do `dpkg --configure --force-depends -a` to get it to work

Answer (score 32):

This usually happens as a result of 'Unmet dependencies for installed packages'.

Here's a simple solution if you have 'Synaptic' installed:

- Open Synaptic.
- Go To 'Status' (in the left navigation).
- Choose 'Broken'.
- Remove these broken packages.

---

Otherwise it can be dealt via CLI:

Open terminal and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Above command will clean out the local repository of retrieved package file.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Will correct broken dependencies i.e. `-f` here stands for “fix broken”.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

will configure all (`-a`) the packages which haven't been configured yet.
In the end do run the update command `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: As a result of this problem, I also failed to load mouse drivers and WLAN drivers. That means I have no more internet connection and can't use `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: You can use an offline/portable package manger i.e Keryx or Cube - help you download packages and latest repositories (in a folder or directly to pendrive) from some other computer with the internet connection (Linux or Windows), once done plug the pendrive to the computer w/o internet connection, and install the downloaded packages.

Comment: A step-by-step tutorial for using Cube (haven't used it myself) - http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1583

Comment: Another askubuntu answer with step-by-step Keryx setup - http://askubuntu.com/a/181913/58950

Comment: I was able to resolve just using `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.. after a reboot I got back network, audio and so on :)

Answer (score 19):

Open [synaptic [image: Install synaptic]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic). Then go to status and choose **Broken**. Then remove completely the broken packages.

This should correct your system.

[image]

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. As soon as I opened Synaptics Software Center, it said the catalog was broken and must be repaired, and offered me a repair button, which cleared up the problem right away.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem, an

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

followed by an

```
sudo apt-get update
```

followed by an

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -f
```

fixed it. I hope this helps!

Comment: As a result of this problem, I also failed to load mouse drivers and WLAN drivers. That means I have no more internet connection and can't use `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Answer (score 4):

Try: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install`
I hope that this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Didn't resolve for me.

Comment: As a result of this problem, I also failed to load mouse drivers and WLAN drivers. That means I have no more internet connection and can't use `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not already, **try changing your package repository reference to 'Main' or the United States**. Doing this fixed my Python-dev unmet-dependencies problem (my 12.04 install *was* using the United Kingdom package repository, previously).

1. In 'Ubuntu Software Center' (USC) go to the menu/tab 'Edit => Software Sources'.
2. Change the 'Download from' drop-down value to 'Main Server' or a server in the United States.
3. Leave USC, the open 'Update Manager' from Ubuntu's program menu, and 'Check' for software update (or issue 'sudo apt-get update' in a terminal window).
4. Update your software as you normally would, e.g. via 'Update Manager' or apt-get/aptitude in a terminal.

This repaired my repository and I went on to install whatever I needed afterwards, as normal.

Before rectifying my problem with the above instructions, various aptitude/apt-get commands suggested that I remove many, many packages, but, as you can apreciate, I didn't fancy loosing my 6-months+ of package additions, and that's even though I snapshot the package list at times (see my [gist](https://gist.github.com/sixman9/3023d73a83a3ec407d83) for hints)! I'm really glad I found out about the instructions I'm leaving here.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be caused by thunderbird

try:

```
sudo apt-get remove  thunderbird
```