# Is there a free trusted virtual machine image with Ubuntu preinstalled?

Tags: virtualization, vmdk

Since the vmware virtual machine drivers are pretty standard I don't see any technical reason for a preinstalled image not to be portable.

Although the above situation is obvious, I didn't find any preinstalled vmware image for Ubuntu.

Is there a trusted free vmware image or an OVF image with Ubuntu preinstalled?

<sup>Note: OVF image works [with most of the players](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Virtualization_Format#Industry_support)!</sup>

Comment: I agree that we need *official* virtual disk images from Canonical or Launchpad, from the official Ubuntu Launchpad project.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ Indeed it would be very useful.

Comment: Wait a minute. Please request an OVF ([Open Virtualization Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Virtualization_Format)) image, rather than a VMware-only image. We'd better have a universal one, for VirtualBox, VMware, Microsoft solutions, etc.

Comment: @gertvdijk thanks, updated to include also OVF, but I am mostly interested in vmware player.

Comment: Why we need pre-made virtual machine images, while we can use iso-disc-image easily with all virtual machine-software for to install ubuntu on virtual-machine's virtual-hard-disk. This quide is for VirtualBox, but works with others same way. So
- create ubuntu virtual machine - include virtual cd-drive and attach ubuntu iso disc image to it - intall ubuntu from virtual cd-drive to virtual hard disk that's it and you have ubuntu virtual machine. That doesn't take much time. http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Seems the same question's already been asked on SuperUser - [Where can I find Ubuntu Desktop releases on a vmdk](https://superuser.com/questions/325140/where-can-i-find-desktop-ubuntu-releases-on-a-vmdk)

The following is the *accepted answer:*

> I have not found any official ubuntu website distributing vmdk's.
>
> According to   http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/
>
> very few suppliers of ubuntu desktop on vmdk exist (3 to be exact).
>
> This seems to be focused on vm creation and distribution, and for now
>   I consider this the de-facto website to go to for ubuntu desktop
>   vmdk's:   http://vmplanet.net/
>
> These guys seem to have vm creation and distribution as a side-project
>   to their main line of business:   http://www.quotrader.com/
>   http://www.bitconstructor.com/

but the *highest-voted answer is as follows:*

> You can find many VMs on [VMware's site](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/1147063).
>
> Open the site and go to "Virtual Appliances"; Ubuntu LTS 11.4 is one
>   of the many images there.
>
> > The newest Ubuntu 11.04 VMware appliance starts out of the box with a
> >     desktop looking like Gnome 2.x, but can be transformed to start the
> >     Unity desktop from Ubuntu. Contrary to the basic Ubuntu 11.04 image
> >     this one has the latest VMware Tools installed.

Note: The [VMware's site](https://solutionexchange.vmware.com/store/category_groups/19) also seems to have Ubuntu 12.04, both desktop and server versions but it's the VMWare store and you have to buy it.

The OP also adds:

> just make sure you have installed the latest vmware player so you
>   don't have problems like I had with vmplayer not being able to run an
>   virtual image made with a newer version.

Comment: VMware's site redirects to their store so those images cost, the cost is not prohibitive but still requires accounts, credit card etc, free would be good

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu Oh I see..The http://vmplanet.net/ link has a lot of `vmdk` files with different distros preinstalled though..

Comment: search no further I am already downloading something from http://vmplanet.net/ and then check back here with result

Comment: nitstorm(accepted), but please make sure to edit your answer and specify that the vmware links http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/  redirects to the store, is fair for the reader, also I tried the vmplanet link and took the 12.04 ubuntu and it works  : vmplanet.net/2012/07/ubuntu-12-04-lts, just make sure you have installed the latest vmware player so you don't have problems like I had with vmplayer not being able to run an virtual image made with a newer version.

Comment: @nitstorm: vmplanet.net looks very promising, thanks for that, but you should definitely paste this link into your answer, I think this way you would get much more upvotes than in the case of linking a site where you can just BUY prebuilt virtual machines... at least from me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

There is an official place where ubuntu distributes it's cloud images (including ovf format):

https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/

Ex, for 14.04 (scroll to page bottom): 
https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/trusty/current/

Comment: Great resource! Here you can find the official releases: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/

Comment: Tried to use an `.ova` file from here. VirtualBox complains about the `.vmdk` inside it being corrupt.

Answer (score 9):

Hyper V has some Ubuntu presets see [Run Ubuntu virtual machines made even easier with Hyper-V Quick Create](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/09/17/run-ubuntu-virtual-machines-made-even-easier-with-hyper-v-quick-create/)

Comment: thoughtplice is down...

Answer (score 2):

The VMWare tools for Fusion-5 doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04LTS. VMware is recommending using Fusion-6 to build a Ubuntu 14.04 image and using it on Fusion-5. Hence finding a pre-built image with VMware tools installed would be great.

I found one, which seems to be working: http://www.trendsigma.net/vmware/ubuntu1404t.html
I'm just not sure of the source.

Answer (score 1):

If you determine that a ready-made image is not available, installing either the server or desktop iso in VMWare Player is exceptionally easy, at least from my limited experience.  On a Win7 Pro, 32-bit, laptop  the Easy Install (most likely a part of VMWare tools) made the installation happen with minimal keyboard work on my part.  About all I needed to supply was my username and password.

Your mileage may vary.

Good luck

Comment: I think that might have proved an easier approach than searching for an vmware clone image but if there is a ready images is way much faster, now that I started this way I will find a solution that will work also for other people (+1)