# Ubuntu ISO file for VMware

Tags: vmware, iso

Where can I download an ISO file for Ubuntu. I want to use it in VMware to mess around.

Answer (score 4):

- You can download the Ubuntu installation ISO file from [**Ubuntu Downloads**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
- If you want **more** options, all supported versions and variants, visit [**releases.ubuntu.com**](http://releases.ubuntu.com/).
- If you are looking for **vmdk** images for testing out things ...

  Here are some answers : [**Is there a free trusted vmware image with Ubuntu preinstalled?**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193336/is-there-a-free-trusted-vmware-image-with-ubuntu-preinstalled)

Answer (score 2):

Download Ubuntu from [Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)