# Installation problems while using VirtualBox on Windows XP

Tags: installation, virtualbox, windows-xp

I'm running Windows XP. I've been trying to load Ubuntu 12.04 in VirtualBox. After first restart, it displays the message:

> please remove installation media and close the try (if any) then press ENTER

Then it stops...
How can I continue?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To quickly remove the installation .iso from virtual box we can select the host CD drive from the *"Devices"*-menu in Virtual Box Manager:

[image]

Alternatively we can also remove the .iso file in the virtual machine's settings.

For a complete guide on how to install Ubuntu in a virtual machine see:

- [How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox)