# Trouble installing Ubuntu 15.04 on a virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox

i am trying to install ubuntu 15.04 on virtualbox. The first time it was established without problems, but now i can not install it again. When i start the machine this error occurs:

[image: Screenshot]

And after installing the optical disk drive disappears from VM and when i start the VM again i offer to install it again.

**Please, help me fix this problem, I urgently need this VM for work.**

Comment: The message in your screenshot isn't the real problem. I can see this message every day and my VM works.

Comment: Maybe this error does not affect the operation of the machine. But why after installation the optical disk disappears and i have to install VM again? As I said, the first installation was successful.Maybe the first installation preserved any files that prevent re-install the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning you see on booting Ubuntu in a Virtual Machine is just to tell you, that in this virtualized environment there is no [System Management Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Bus). This of course is expected, as we do not install on bare metal. We can safely ignore this warning.

After installing Ubuntu from the .ISO file we have to **remove** this virtual CD-ROM from the virtual machine to be able to boot from the virtual hard drive (.VDI) we had created. Otherwise it will just boot again from the CD image which will offer you to re-install (see e.g. [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282413/installation-problems-while-using-virtualbox-on-windows-xp)).

Comment: Thank you, it means that disappearance of the optical disc is normal. But why I cannot run the VM? Installing window appears again.

Comment: What I do is to replace the virtual CD drive (in Virtual Box Manger storage settings) with either the host CD-drive, or I load the guest additions CD instead. In any case if you see the installer again your Ubuntu ISO was not removed from the VM.

Comment: @ Takkat Thank you very much! I removed the disk from the drive and it worked.