# Can I use Ubuntu in a virtual machine?

Tags: installation, virtualbox, virtualization

I am a novice, the computer illiterate. I heard that Ubuntu is free, and would like to try it, but my video card seems not to be supported. I heard of virtual machines.

Can Oracle Virtual Box run Ubuntu? If so, is there anything I should do? If not, what would be a better solution?

Comment: Here is a short guide to start with: http://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

Yes, VirtualBox can handle Ubuntu.Just install it and read the instruction/help files that come with it to create virtual machines.

You will need an .iso image of Ubuntu which you can download from www.ubuntu.com

Comment: don't say thanks, but upvote hmayaq's answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:
Yes you may download and use the Ubuntu .iso on the Virtualbox software which is free to use.
It comes for windows version as well.
https://www.virtualbox.org/‎

You need to mount that .iso file and just run that.

Option 2:
You may download the Live CD version of the Ubuntu Operating system and simply boot it with that live CD."Make sure you click on TRY UBUNTU"
This will leave you with user experience of how the OS looks like.