# how to set up a virtual server and install Ubuntu on it?

Tags: installation, virtualbox, setup

After installing Virtual box, I need to set up a virtual server and install Ubuntu on it. What steps should I take?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Ubuntu Server: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server
2. Use that with the [VirtualBox documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html) for creating a new virtual machine.

Ubuntu Server is a fairly basic install but your question is really "How do I use VirtualBox?". Reading the manual (and playing with VB) is the only way you're going to learn how to use it.

If you need a step-by-step, you can easily find them. We even have some on here:

- [How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox) (yeah the first 99% is all VirtualBox and is exactly the same for Ubuntu Server)

Comment: I have installed ubuntu server on virtual box. My question really should be how to install Ubuntu onto my Ubuntu virtual server? or is this correct question at all? I have also installed Ubuntu to virtualbox, so I have separately Ubuntu and Ubuntu server, but now I have been told to install Ubuntu on the virtual server and it is confusing me.