# Simply, running an Ubuntu Server through Virtualbox?

Tags: server, virtualbox

When I go through official documentation (which isn't so great) I cannot figure out how to run an Ubuntu Sever through Virtual box. I cannot find an option, and my iso is never a proper iso to boot from in the storage options... any help would be great or maybe pointing me to a good tutorial would be awesome. I just want to mess around and see what up. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question for details on what you tried to install Ubuntu server, and possible errors you get. For server the installation is the same as depicted here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity I'd recommend the 32bit version. If you know what you're doing with VirtualBox, you can download the 64bit version.

Then it's just a case of building a VM in VirtualBox and booting from the downloaded ISO:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After that just follow the prompts.