# Can I install 32-bit Ubuntu in a 64-bit host using VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, 32-bit

After countless problems trying to program NASM Assembly in a 64-bit Ubuntu install in VirtualBox, I figured I'd just go to 32-bit programming for now.

I'm no expert - can I install 32-bit Ubuntu in VirtualBox, where the host is 64-bit?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, you can install a 32-bit Ubuntu virtual system in a 64-bit host.

**To do this, follow these steps:**

1. Install VirtualBox from the Ubuntu Software Center.
2. Download the desired Ubuntu ISO file (32-bit in your case from [the Ubuntu page](http://download.ubuntu.com)).
3. Create a new machine from the File → New menu.
4. Make sure that you select the "Ubuntu" OS (instead of "Ubuntu (64-bit)").
5. Setup your other options.
6. Launch the virtual machine and install Ubuntu (select the downloaded ISO file when prompted for a CD or DVD media).
7. After installing Ubuntu and "rebooting", install the VirtualBox drivers.
8. Setup the new installation as desired.

---

I hope that this will help you solve your problem.

*Edit:* I found a [video on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV23KKsCKn4) that explains how to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox (in case that you did not use VirtualBox before).