# Android emulator independent of Virtual Box/VM-ware capability

Tags: software-recommendation, android-emulator

While searching for an Android emulator I found "Genymotion" or "AndroVM" which I can't use because my Laptop is not capable of running virtual machines.

I need an emulator independent of VM's like Virtual Box, prefer options like GPS or Android device configurations.

Comment: Why is your laptop incapable of running virtual machines? An android emulator is at some level gonna be a virtiaul macihne.

Comment: VT-x technology is not supported by my laptop CPU. @vidarlo

Comment: What about the official Android emulator? You said nothing about trying that one. In any case, you have to virtualize Android one way or another. Unless your laptop is 20 years old, VT-x will be an option to be activated in the BIOS.

Comment: You should still be able to run a 32 bit VM without VT-X using for instance virtualbox.

Comment: Lenovo G550 @AndreaLazzarotto , No , I did not try official Android emulator, I will give it a shut

Comment: running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64, can I run 32 bit VM?

Comment: Comments are the worst possible place to ask new questions, especially given that we already have an answered version of your question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/344976/can-i-install-32-bit-ubuntu-in-a-64-bit-host-using-virtualbox

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto , tnx in advance but the major problem is that I can not use any Virtual box. I tried installing Android official emulator via [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu) but it needs virtual box too.

Comment: There is no need of VirtualBox. As a matter of fact, it is sufficient to install Android Studio to get the emulator. Also, the fact that you can virtualize 32 bit on top of 64 bit is not VirtualBox specific, it's a universal fact.

Answer (score 1):

[Anbox](https://anbox.io/), seems to be active.

[Shashlik](http://www.shashlik.io/), as of writing the words last activity on github was 2016 year, so could be abandoned.

[Archon](https://archon-runtime.github.io/), a runtime for running Android in Chrome. If I am correct that [this is the code](https://github.com/vladikoff/chromeos-apk/) *(I am not sure because its name is distinct for some reason; but the front page points there, and google didn't give other links)*, then as of writing the words last activity was in 2015 year.

I can't remember the names, but there is a few more *(AFAIK inactive)* projects of that sort.

Either way it boils down mostly to amount of devs wanting to work on that. So if you occasionally know devs or CS students or just enthusiasts wanting to run Android natively on their desktop, point them to try joining one of those projects ;)

Comment: while trying install Anbox, I got this error: `Setting up ubuntu-core-launcher (2.26.10) ...` newline 
`Setting up snap-confine (2.26.10) ...`  newline
`Errors were encountered while processing:` newline
 `virtualbox-ext-pack`  newline
`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: @Mirza how do you installing it? [Looking at anboxᴬᵁᴿ](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=anbox-git#n57) I see no dependencies on VirtualBox, and [the official guide uses snap](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/wiki/Installation) *(however I hate snap and flatpack, sometimes for users it might be a good thing)*.

Comment: previous error was while installing snap but even trying to install Anbox according to [www.anbox.io](https://www.anbox.io) by running `snap install --classic anbox-installer && anbox-installer ` in terminal, I got the same error as `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: @Mirza I don't know in general because there could be many reasons, and I am not even using a distro with the same package manager. Besides this is not directly related to the question so you might have better luck asking a separate question. But out off top of my head: have you tried [the officially recommended command](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/wiki/Installation), i.e. `snap install --edge --devmode anbox`?

Answer (score 0):

A little while ago I read an article on maketecheasier.com that is highly relevant to your question. I will link the article below.

https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-android-apps-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Did not work. `Errors were encountered while processing:  
 virtualbox-ext-pack   
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Ack. Let me look into that.

Comment: When did you get that error?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @MichaelKnoll : at the middle of installing via terminal