# Attempting to install Ubuntu on Oracle Virtual Box inside Win 7

Tags: installation, virtualbox

After I get the ubuntu install completion message how do I shut down the virtual machine and reload so the VM will point to the new install rather than the install .iso image file?. I flashed the bios to the latest version for my pc successfully.

Thanks in advance,

dave

Comment: see last image of my answer there: http://askubuntu.com/a/153098/3940

Answer (score 0):

Look Here: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-storage

It explains how to add and remove storage

Or Simply

```
Click Option>Storage>Remove the ISO
```

Tell me if this worked!

Answer (score 0):

In the running machine virtual box menu,

Click on "Devices -> CD/DVD Devices -> Remove disk from virtual drive" then reboot.

If the machine is already shutdown you can remove it in the "Settings -> storage" options

Comment: that is exactly what i just said.

Comment: @samgabbay Yes you are right that's answer collision :)  (It took time to recheck all the options names). Somebody put you down I think he should have explain why.