# Please remove installation media and close tray message inside Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, restart, crash

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 inside a virtual machine running in Windows 7. I've been getting this message every time after the installer asks for a restart. What should I do?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox last image in the top answer.

Answer (score 24):

Just to be clear: you can just hit enter when you see this message after installing inside Virtual Box and Ubuntu will restart normally.

Comment: It's similar to the problem of not being able to find "any" key on the keyboard when we are asked to: "Press any key to continue."

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the VM is set to boot the hard disk you installed Ubuntu to first, then restart.

The message is designed to make sure that users don't accidently start the installer a second time. The easiest way of making absolutely sure that doesn't happen is having them remove the CD from the drive.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, issue is that you didn't start the whole virtual machine so the iso disk is still inserted in it ( kindof ) , if you close the machine and then start again , it will no longer think that the disk is not attached. so just close the machine and start the machine again. Ubuntu should open without any problem.