# downloading and running on virtual box

Tags: installation

I am downloading ubuntu for the first time.  I am planning on installing it on a virtual machine.  Will I need to install it from a dvd copy, or will I be able to install it from my hard drive?

Comment: You can either install from DVD, USB, or use the ISO directly from the hard drive.

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/142549/176889

Answer (score 1):

What virtualization software are you planning to use?  I run Oracle VirtualBox, and it has a setting in the "Storage" segment of the settings screen that will allow you to select the .iso image as an actual CD-ROM.

In the same area, set your drive boot sequence to boot from the cd device, and start up the virtual machine.