# Make modded .iso bootable

Tags: boot, virtualbox, iso, archive, zip

I used archive maneger to extract a tinycore .iso (tinycore is a Linux distro) so I could diddle around. (Change the boot screen to my name, you know) I then used package maneger again to zip the files back up into a .iso, the only problem was that when I try it in vbox, it says "no bootable medium found". I am sure there is something simple I am missing, but what is it?
Thanks

Comment: Try checking the answers on [What does “No bootable medium found” mean in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/q/413594/301745)

Comment: @wjandrea that is no the problem, I created a virtual box hard disk and selected the ISO, the issue is the ISO.  I am certain that the disk is not the problem, because I can boot regular tinycore fine on the same settings, but my new version doesn't work.

Comment: Your problem is that when you extract an iso, it does not keep the bootloader. This may be what you want, or at least similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso