# My Ubuntu VM keeps wanting to reinstall Ubuntu!

Tags: virtualbox

I've already installed ubuntu 12.04 in Virtual Machine but whenever I shut down the machine and open the Virtual Machine again it keeps asking to install it again?

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the host machine? Is this problem specific to VirtualBox? Did you try other hypervisors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox) **Step 7. in the answer there.**

Answer (score 18):

You have to disable the CD/DVD option in virtual box settings or changing the boot-order to hard-disk as the first option will make you to boot into your installed Ubuntu OS.

- On your virtualbox right-click on the Ubuntu virtual machine and select the Settings option.
- Go to system tab and change the boot-order like in the below screenshot.And finally select OK option.

[image]

- Now start your virtual machine.It will surely boot your installed Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Tiny update: CD/DVD is now called Optical.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like your virtual machine is booting from the installation media.

In virtual box go to your virtual machines configuration and  ensure that you remove the live usb / disk image from the available devices section.