# The medium can't be used as the requested device type

Tags: virtualbox

I recently tried downloaded Kali and I don't want to run it along side my current Ubuntu 13.10. Instead I intend to run it through VM VirtualBox (downloaded from Software Centre).

Here is what I entered into the first set-up stage:

- Name: Kali Linux
- Type: Linux
- Version: Linux 2.6 (this I am not so sure on? should it be Debian)

All is well in setting the RAM and disk size etc.
But when it comes to loading the Kali ISO (32bit) I am confronted with this perplexing error message.

[image: img]

Failed to open the CD/DVD image /home/anonhalo/VirtualBox VMs/kali-linux-1.0.6-i386.iso.

> The medium '/home/anonhalo/VirtualBox VMs/kali-linux-1.0.6-i386.iso' can't be used as the requested device type.

In my own head I am thinking it is the file location of the ISO? But I moved it to 10 different locations. And still the same error?

Comment: also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way, you are trying to add an ISO image as a CD/DVD drive. Instead, first, create the new VM, using Debian 32bit as the OS type. Then, once this has been created, go into the VM's Settings and choose the "Storage" tab. Once there, select the "Empty" item under the IDE controller:

[image]

Then, click on the CD icon on the top right, and select the 1st choice,

[image]

In the dialog that will appear, select the Kali .iso, save the settings and then boot the machine. It will boot from the .iso you just selected and you should be able to istall with no problems.

Comment: That saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the image file is of kind ISO disk image in the properties. I had the same problem as the kind of file was as Folder and Not ISO disk image eventhough it had iso extension. Just double click the folder and copy the disk image file into new hard disk partition. Now use this path for loading in the Virtualbox in the storage option. This method worked for me.