# VMLite Guest Addition Error

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, guest-additions

I tried to install the guest addition of VMLite based on Virtual Box on a x86 Ubuntu 12.04.4. I used a Guest Addition ISO Image for VirtualBox 3.2.6. Of course I am just a Windows user and don't know anything about Ubuntu or Linux. I also tried to kind of update the Linux headers. It did not worked too. Does anybody know what I must do to get the Guest Addition installed?

Some phrases are in German:

```
Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden - File or Directory not found
schwerwiegender Fehler - hard error
Fehler - mistake or error
```

Excuse me, I can't understand how to get a spoiler. Here is the error log:

```
grep: /lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
    echo >&2;                           \
    echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
    echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
    echo >&2 ;                          \
    /bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
grep: /lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.test.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -mno-mmx -mno-sse -fno-pic -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wa,-mtune=generic32 -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -pg -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -I/lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -D_X86_ -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBGL_HGCM -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(test)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxadd_test)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_test.o /tmp/vbox.0/test.c
  if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /tmp/vbox.0/test.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/scripts/recordmcount  "/tmp/vbox.0/test.o"; fi; fi;
  ld -m elf_i386   -r -o /tmp/vbox.0/vboxadd_test.o /tmp/vbox.0/test.o 
(cat /dev/null;   echo kernel//tmp/vbox.0/vboxadd_test.ko;) > /tmp/vbox.0/modules.order
make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/scripts/Makefile.modpost
grep: /lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
  find /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions -name '*.mod' | xargs -r grep -h '\.ko$' | sort -u | sed 's/\.ko$/.o/' | scripts/mod/modpost -m -a -i /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/Module.symvers -I /tmp/vbox.0/Module.symvers  -o /tmp/vbox.0/Module.symvers -S -w -s -T -
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.vboxadd_test.mod.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -mno-mmx -mno-sse -fno-pic -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wa,-mtune=generic32 -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -pg -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -I/lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -D_X86_ -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBGL_HGCM -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxadd_test.mod)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxadd_test)" -DMODULE  -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/vboxadd_test.mod.o /tmp/vbox.0/vboxadd_test.mod.c
  ld -r -m elf_i386 -T /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/scripts/module-common.lds --build-id  -o /tmp/vbox.0/vboxadd_test.ko /tmp/vbox.0/vboxadd_test.o /tmp/vbox.0/vboxadd_test.mod.o
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.header:87: Ignoring unknown BUILD_TYPE value '_BUILDTYPE_'.
grep: /lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
    echo >&2;                           \
    echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
    echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
    echo >&2 ;                          \
    /bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.header:93: Using BUILD_TYPE='release' from the environment.
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.test_drm.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -mno-mmx -mno-sse -fno-pic -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wa,-mtune=generic32 -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -pg -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -I/lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DLOG_TO_BACKDOOR -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DIN_MODULE -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DRT_ARCH_X86  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(test_drm)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxadd_test_drm)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_test_drm.o /tmp/vbox.0/test_drm.c
  if [ "-pg" = "-pg" ]; then if [ /tmp/vbox.0/test_drm.o != "scripts/mod/empty.o" ]; then /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/scripts/recordmcount  "/tmp/vbox.0/test_drm.o"; fi; fi;
  ld -m elf_i386   -r -o /tmp/vbox.0/vboxadd_test_drm.o /tmp/vbox.0/test_drm.o 
(cat /dev/null;   echo kernel//tmp/vbox.0/vboxadd_test_drm.ko;) > /tmp/vbox.0/modules.order
make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/scripts/Makefile.modpost
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.header:93: Using BUILD_TYPE='release' from the environment.
  find /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions -name '*.mod' | xargs -r grep -h '\.ko$' | sort -u | sed 's/\.ko$/.o/' | scripts/mod/modpost -m -a -i /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/Module.symvers -I /tmp/vbox.0/Module.symvers  -o /tmp/vbox.0/Module.symvers -S -w -s -T -
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.vboxadd_test_drm.mod.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -mno-mmx -mno-sse -fno-pic -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wa,-mtune=generic32 -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -pg -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -I/lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DLOG_TO_BACKDOOR -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DIN_MODULE -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DRT_ARCH_X86  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxadd_test_drm.mod)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxadd_test_drm)" -DMODULE  -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/vboxadd_test_drm.mod.o /tmp/vbox.0/vboxadd_test_drm.mod.c
  ld -r -m elf_i386 -T /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/scripts/module-common.lds --build-id  -o /tmp/vbox.0/vboxadd_test_drm.ko /tmp/vbox.0/vboxadd_test_drm.o /tmp/vbox.0/vboxadd_test_drm.mod.o
Attempting to install using DKMS

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/3.2.6/source ->
                 /usr/src/vboxguest-3.2.6

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
make KERNELRELEASE=3.11.0-19-generic -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/3.2.6/build....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for vboxguest: 3.2.6 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.11.0-19-generic (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/3.2.6/build/make.log for more information.
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
grep: /lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
    echo >&2;                           \
    echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
    echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
    echo >&2 ;                          \
    /bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.VBoxGuest-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -mno-mmx -mno-sse -fno-pic -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wa,-mtune=generic32 -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -pg -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -I/lib/modules/3.11.0-19-generic/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DVBOX -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_GUEST -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DIN_MODULE -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBGL_VBOXGUEST -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DRT_ARCH_X86  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(VBoxGuest_linux)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxguest)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_VBoxGuest-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.c
In file included from /tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/the-linux-kernel.h:34:0,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.c:27:
/tmp/vbox.0/include/iprt/types.h:97:31: schwerwiegender Fehler: linux/autoconf.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Kompilierung beendet.
make[2]: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/VBoxGuest-linux.o] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vbox.0] Fehler 2
make: *** [vboxguest] Fehler 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Support for X-Server > 1.10 was added in virtual box version 4.06 release 2 years ago. Therefore in 12.04 which provides X 1.11.4 we can not install guest additions from an older virtualbox release.

This is even more so for the kernel 3.11 you obviously had installed in this machine. Kernel 3.11 however is of Ubuntu release 13.10, not 12.04.

All this makes me believe that you have quite a mixed setup here. Your best approach to avoid such issues is to install the most recent version of Virtual Box with an up-to-date Ubuntu.

- [Download Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
- [Download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)
- [How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox)
- [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox/22745#22745)

Comment: Thanks. I tried out Ubuntu 13.10 on VMLite (not on VirtualBox) and the Guest Addition works. I just had to install the additional drivers in Ubuntu like in V12. But in V13 it works :-)