# Trying to download and install Ubuntu on my Mac

Tags: macbook

I clicked the link to download.  I tried to click this "ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso" from my Downloads folder and received the message: "No mountable file systems".

What can I do?

Comment: Do you follow a tutorial to install Ubuntu? Which one?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Disk Utility gui application. (Easy way to find it: Search using spotlight.)
2. Drag the original .iso from Finder into the images section of Disk Utility (on the left side underneath the mounted drive list), and then double click on it there. A faded "diskNs1" should appear underneath it, and a dialog box will say the disk is not mountable. The "diskNs1" is the embedded .iso.
3. Run "dd if=/disk/rdiskNs1 of=./ubuntu-extracted.iso bs=1m" to copy out the working .iso image.

The output file was exactly identical to the input file (the file sizes and md5s match) except for the name.

source : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1870261&page=5

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do with Ubuntu? What you have downloaded is a disk image i.e. equivalent to a DVD. Ubuntu is an Operating System and I dont know of a way to install it directly on top of another O/S - doubt there is one to be honest!

You need to get hold of VM software such as VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org/) and then follow something along the lines of this: [How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox)