# How to make Ubuntu Gnome display bigger in Virtualbox?

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, display-resolution, guest-additions

I am doing a project for my operating systems class. In Virtualbox, I have already installed the Guest additions and restarted, but it is still the same screen resolution.  I am using the "Try Ubuntu" option since I do not want to get rid of the Windows 7 that I already have on my computer. I am using Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 desktop and Vitrualbox 4.3.20. I have never dealt with Ubuntu before, so I am a complete novice.

Comment: So are you seeing Ubuntu gnome inside Virtualbox? If you are using virtualbox it means you are running a virtual nachine inside windows. If you use the install option on the virtual machine, you will not change anything on the so-called host operating system. Once you installed it, you can install guest additions to get better resolution.

Comment: try to make a new one and this time before booting into iso make sure you increase video graphics and system ram in settings

Answer (score 0):

A guest operating system installed in Virtual Box will not alter the host operating system in any way other than using some hard drive space for a **virtual** disk.

[Installing Ubuntu in Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox) will not affect your host installation. In fact it is a good approach to test Ubuntu and it's various flavours without the need to repartition a hard drive.

To be able to run Ubuntu in variable screen resolutions and to be able to benefit from a virtual graphics adapter for hardware video acceleration we need to [install the guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) within the guest. These will install as a kernel module loaded on booting the guest.

Therefore guest additions will not be available when booting a live system ("Try out Ubuntu"). They need a proper installation on a virtual drive.