# install Ubuntu 14.04.01 on windows 7 x64 faced nonetype error

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, wubi

Greeting to everyone, 
I am new to Linux but urge to install it for my project using virtual machine.
I try to install it using virtual clone drive.

I mount it on virtual clone drive and wubi.exe pop up for installation.
After I set my password, it run installation and finally give me an error:

'None Type' object has no attribute 'get_info'....

May I know what is going wrong?

After it failed, I run the installation using USB stick by "open portable device".
Unfortunately, it also didn't work.

After that, I re download the ISO file and put them at same folder and install again, but same error came up...

Is that it MUST be run on DVD?

Comment: That's a null reference exception in Python. The log will show the call stack so it's clear what object is being referenced. Since you've not included the log file I'd guess that it's the same problem as [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/989991). i.e. an MD5 checksum failure and bad exception handling logic. Wubi is not recommended. If you want to install Ubuntu in a virtual machine, then you shouldn't be using Wubi. Download the ISO, make sure it's okay (md5 check), then set the ISO as a virtual CD for the VM and boot from it to install.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox)