# i was trying to install ubuntu on virtual box in windows 8.1 and got an error

Tags: boot, system-installation, virtualbox

```
Failed to open the optical disk file D:\programm setups\ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso.

Could not get the storage format of the medium 'D:\programm setups\ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: Medium
Interface: IMedium {05f2bbb6-a3a6-4fb9-9b49-6d0dda7142ac}
Callee: IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

Comment: Your ISO file may be corrupted, or read acces to that file may be an issue. Try to copy to a different location (avoid spaces in path), or download again.

Comment: Did you [verify the checksum](//help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows) of the image file? Otherwise this looks like a question about a Windows VM solution, which is off topic here.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: **boderline off topic** - we should support questions on how to install Ubuntu (even it was in a VM) but obviously we can't help when issues come from the host Windows. Nevertheless we have a good tutorial for this here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox