# How can I install Kubuntu on a Virtualbox with a dynamic hard drive?

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu

When I try to install Kubuntu on my Virtualbox, it says that there isn't enough space:

[image]

I think this is because I chose to have a dynamically allocated VDI hard drive. Is there any way to install it onto the VDI i've created?

---

[How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox#) doesn't solve it because I know how to install, I just get stuck at the instalation of Kubuntu because it doesn't think the disk is big enough (I even tried formatting, and it was still saying less than 1 MB).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox)

Comment: @Takkat I did all that. I couldn't install on the VDI - look at the picture. It said there wasn't enough space. I'd given it 50 GB.

Comment: Your answer may cause confusion, as there you clearly show all steps needed to install Ubuntu in Virtual Box which makes it an exact duplicate to the question I linked. Using another virtual hard disk format is possible but not recommended. VHD is a Microsoft format which is supported but it definitely does not work better than the Virtual Box VDI format.

Comment: @Takkat well my answer was how I got it working for me. It's not a duplicate because that one *didn't work for me*.

Comment: Your issues likely came from something else but not from using Microsoft VHD instead of Virtual Box VDI format.

Comment: @Takkat No, I was using VDI at the begining. Then I switched to VHD  when that didn't work,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can. However, you can create a dynamically allocated VHD instead.

Here is how to create it:

Click settings, and then Storage and click Controller: SATA. Then click the Blue square with a green `+`.

[image]

Click Create new disk:

[image]

Chose VHD and click Next:

[image]

Chose Dynamically allocated, and click next:

[image]

Chose a name, a size and click Create:

[image]

You will be able to install Kubuntu on this, it detects it as a full sized HDD. And don't worry about wasting space with the old VDI - you can either remove it, or just ignore it - mine is 3.1 MB.

Comment: Of course you can use VDI. Just choose an appropirate size when you create it, like 8GB. then you can isntall ubuntu in there without problem. The VDI on disk will grow accordingly of the size needed.

Comment: @solsTiCe I did. It was 50GB. It didn't work - try it. Do you have a reason why it didn't? The -1 seems unnecessary, especially as this worked for the OP.

Comment: OK. I just tried with kubuntu 14.04 in a 50GB VDI. No problem here. May be it's your setup, guest or host.

Comment: @solsTiCe perhaps. I tried twice and both times it said that the VDI was 1.1 bytes.

Comment: Is it a new VDI or an alreay used one ?

Comment: @solsTiCe brand new, when I created the VM VB.