# Trying to create a virtual machine but am stuck on permission error

Tags: permissions, virtualbox

I am trying to create a virtual machine in Virtual Machine Manager, but every time I click on the ISO file it says it couldn't read the contents of the folder that it is in.  I have never used ubuntu before and am having a hard time finding a solution online.

Comment: Well I could not find out how to get the permissions, but I added the .iso file to my desktop to solve my issue.

Comment: Please give us some idea of what you are planning to do. What is your host OS? What guest OS do you try to install? How was virtualbox installed?

Comment: Also, have you seen this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox?

Comment: Host OS is Ubuntu and guest OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.  Virtual Box was installed from the terminal