# Installing Ubuntu on Oracle VM Virtual Box Manager:Partition

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox

Installing Ubuntu on Oracle VM Virtual Box Manager. I haven't done any partitioning in Windows. During the Installation, I have a notification box saying this:

[image: installer screenshot: Write the changes to disk?]

My Question is:  What is the next step to be done to Install Linux ?
Should I continue or go back and make changes beforehand ?

Comment: Check out [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox) on how to install Ubuntu in Oracle virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can continue

This is a **normal** confirm message. It just shows the partitions the installer will write. This is nessesary, to install Ubuntu.