# How to remove your installation .iso from the virtual optical disk drive in virtualbox?

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, iso

I am following this question: [How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox) and I know want to remove the .iso, but it's not the same as in that question. Here is what I see:

[image]

What I should do?

---

I also tried from *Machine -> Settings -> Storage*, where I could locate the .iso file in the Storage Tree, but the right click on it, is giving me a list with one item, *Remove attachment*, but it's disabled.

Comment: I see "Remove disk from virtual drive", ...looks good enough.

Comment: Oh is that OK @mikewhatever, I thought it meant the hard disk, let's see. I did that, I pressed Restart Now, it remains clicked..and I wait. Is this normal, I ask myself? :/

Comment: You removed the disk while the computer was running off of it. It's ok to click the X in the top left and click "Power off the machine"

Comment: Thank you @Grammargeek, that should be a good edit in your answer. ;)

Comment: Oh, and just a little fun fact, if you clicked "Restart Now", Ubuntu would have ejected the disk for you :)

Comment: You do read Release Notes? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WilyWerewolf/ReleaseNotes It says a bug on virtual installs. `unable to press ENTER to reboot. Powering off and back on should boot you into your installed system. This is being tracked in bug 1447038`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Devices>CD/DVD Devices>Remove disk from virtual drive" from the top bar on your screen.

If you accidentally remove it while the VM is still running off of it, you can press the host key (usually the Windows flag on the left of your keyboard) and R to reboot it.