# How do I finish my Ubuntu installation on virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu on virtual box and shut down the machine when prompted to restart the computer. However, when I turned it back on it asked to install the program again. When I got to the page where it asks if you want to install Ubuntu on its own or have it run with the current OS it shows the Ubuntu that I had already installed. How do I access the one I installed already?
[Installation Type Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73EpI.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove your installation .iso from the virtual optical disk drive in virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724442/how-to-remove-your-installation-iso-from-the-virtual-optical-disk-drive-in-virt)

Answer (score 0):

Eject disk from your Virtual Machine or restart machine and start press F12 to open boot menu (if EFI enabled, ESC key.), select HDD.

[image]