# Can i set up an Ubuntu virtual machine on Windows (Oracle VirtualBox)?

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, windows, virtualbox, windows-8

I am new to the Ubuntu OS. I was wondering if I could use this operating system through an Oracle VirtualBox virtual machine on Windows as I do not want to switch my computer's OS. It is a Hewlett-Packard PC running Windows 8.1.  If this is already in an FAQ somewhere, I'm sorry as I have not looked because I'm lazy.  I have heard great things about this OS and I want to try it for myself. It does not mean that I'm going to be switching for good, I just want to try it on a virtual machine. Thank you in advance. P.S. this is for personal use and I'm using the free version.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can use Ubuntu, or almost any other OS in a virtual machine in Virtual Box. Just download the ISO image, and boot the virtual machine from there. Install the OS, or try it in live mode if you want. You can also test the Ubuntu ISO, burning it into a Live USB, and using your own computer, booting from the USB Media.

For more information, look at this thread:

[How to install Ubuntu in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox)

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you! The ISO just finished downloading, and I'm going to set up the Virtual Machine now.

Comment: When the question has been asked before with an acceptable answer, it should be marked duplicate and the other post then linked.

Comment: Oh, that's true, ok, removing comment, thanks for the clarification!, already marked.