# Crossair Void 7.1 Alternative Drivers

Tags: drivers, sound, hardware, headphones, headset

I've recently bought a new headset, the Crossair Void 7.1. And now I cannot find any drivers for Ubuntu. The headset sorta works, but I cannot use it to it's full potential without Windows...

It would be so nice if there were some alternative drivers that I could use to enable Dolby and 7.1.

if it doesn't work, do you think it's possible to setup a virtual machine in Windows and install the drivers / Google Play Music on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It seems like there is no drives for the crossair void 7.1
   Here is a link to a simmilar question :

http://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=153831

2. Yes you can sertenly install virtual box then create a windows 7 virtual pc

Here is a link on how to setup virual box:

[How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox)

I'm sure it still applies to you.

Comment: Okey... I thought in Linux there was a way for anything but sadly nope... I will go complain at Crossair for not supporting a populair platform like Linux. Thanks anyways, I'll accept your answer.