# Issue with installing Ubuntu onto my Virtual Machine

Tags: xubuntu

I have watched many videos, but all seem to not have the issue I am having. I try to install Ubuntu for Virtual Box but every time it is requiring me to burn Ubuntu onto a disc, is there a way so that it is not necessary to burn it onto a physical disc? They call it an ISO image. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a question for the OS you are hosting the Virtual Machine on, and/or a question for the Virtual Machine software.

With VirtualBox, if you want to install Ubuntu from an ISO image, the first thing you will want to do is create your virtual machine with a blank Virtual Hard Disk.

Then in the **VirtualBox Manager**, you go to **Storage** and associate your ISO image with that Virtual Hard Disk.  Your virtual machine will then boot from the ISO, allowing you to install Ubuntu onto the virtual machine.

This web-page explains [How to Install Ubuntu into Virtual Box From an ISO Image](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox)

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to burn a physical disc to install Ubuntu on your virtual machine.

What you need to do is [download the Ubuntu ISO file](https://www.ubuntu.com/download), and use that file when VirtualBox asks for the installation disc (the ISO image).

There's a very good (but somewhat dated) step-by-step of using the ISO file when creating a new Ubuntu virtual machine in VirtualBox. Details [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/153098/32664).