# Can't run binary executable from terminal

Tags: command-line, binary

I am trying to run the binary found at this site http://shaddack.brutowave.com/projects/sw_qr2laser/ I set it to executable and try and run ...

```
laptop@XPS15:~/Downloads$ qr2laser
qr2laser: command not found
laptop@XPS15:~/Downloads$
```

or ...

```
  laptop@XPS15:~/Downloads$ ./qr2laser
  ./qr2laser: error while loading shared libraries: libMagickWand.so.5: 
  cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  laptop@XPS15:~/Downloads$
```

It requires imagemagick to run and this is installed.

I have also tried to compile the source code but I also have errors relating to imagemagick.

Is this a reference error? Should imagemagick bein a different path?

Comment: That's some old software. 12.04 uses libmagickwand 6.6, 18.04 is likely to use 6.9, so for 5.0 you're out of luck. To compile, you need the libmagickwand-6-headers package, available in 16.04 and newer.

Comment: I installed a VM on 12.04 and got a pretty much identical result.

Comment: Please try to compile the software from source as explained in my answer. If you encounter any warning or error messages please reproduce them in their entirety in your question ([edit]) using the [formatting tools](https://$SITEURL$/help/formatting). In my opinion, using the precompiled binary should be the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

The only currently supported version of Ubuntu where `libmagickwand5` is available is 14.04 (supported until April 2019), so installing it is one possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways here, you can either

1. compile the software for your exact system from its source `qr2laser.c` or
2. use the binary `qr2laser` as you tried.

The first one is what you should try first. Compiling on your system means the compiler will dig through your exact system to find the programs and libraries your software needs and create a binary. If there are missing dependencies, i.e. the compiler can't find programs your software needs, you will get a nice error message informing you what's wrong.
The second one has the downside that your system needs to have the same prerequisites as the system where the binary was compiled. In your case that's obviously not the case, and if you don't happen to use Ubuntu 14.04 it's hard (and not a good idea overall!) to install the missing `libMagickWand.so.5` library.

#### Compile the software yourself (the way to go)

1. Install the necessary compiler and your software's prerequisites:

   ```
   sudo apt install gcc libmagickwand-6.q16-2
   ```
2. Download your software's source code:

   ```
   wget http://shaddack.brutowave.com/projects/sw_qr2laser/qr2laser.c
   ```
3. Compile it:

   ```
   gcc -std=c99 -o qr2laser `pkg-config --cflags --libs MagickWand` qr2laser.c
   ```
4. If everything went through without errors you will now have a `qr2laser` binary you can start:

   ```
   ./qr2laser
   ```

#### Use the precompiled binary (the last resort)

When it comes to old software a virtual machine is *the* way to go because you don't flood your working installation with hoary software.

1. Install `virtualbox`:

   ```bsh
   sudo apt install virtualbox
   sudo apt install virtualbox-ext-pack # optional, for e.g. USB 2.0 support
   ```
2. Set up a virtual machine and install a matching OS, Ubuntu 14.04 in this case.

   - [Download the `.iso`](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/)
   - [How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox)
3. Inside the VM, install your software's prerequisites and run it:

   ```bsh
   sudo apt install libmagickwand5
   /path/to/qr2laser
   ```

Comment: I installed 14.04 in a VM. No matter what angle I attack this I get the following error ..

qr2laser.c:(.text+0x1ead): undefined reference to `MagickWandGenesis'
qr2laser.c:(.text+0x1eb2): undefined reference to `NewMagickWand'
qr2laser.c:(.text+0x1ef1): undefined reference to `MagickReadImage'
qr2laser.c:(.text+0x1f2a): undefined reference to `MagickGetException'
qr2laser.c:(.text+0x1f6a): undefined reference to `MagickRelinquishMemory'
qr2laser.c:(.text+0x1f84): undefined reference to `MagickGetImageWidth'
qr2laser.c:(.text+0x1f96): undefined reference to `MagickGetImageHeight'

Comment: Yes, using the precompiled binary may be not a good idea at all, even in the VM you may not be able to recreate the system the binary was compiled for. Did you try compiling from source?

Comment: This was the result of compiling from source

Comment: Why did you compile in the VM? Use your normal system for that!

Comment: When I try and install the prerequisite on my system I get this error 

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-6.q16-2 : Depends: libmagickcore-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.9.9) but it is not going to be installed
                         PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.17.6)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @ToyTeardown You did try the solutions proposed in correspondent questions like [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages), didn't you?