# i was trying to install ubuntu on virtualbox, but i'm ending up with the screen mentioned below. please let me know if u have solution for this

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

I couldn't understand what is this. I've installed Ubuntu before but never faced this issue. 
[image]

Comment: Make sure that the install media you used to install Ubuntu to the VM is no longer mounted with the install ISO

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox    i followed this, why isn't that working

Comment: Please ensure that no ISO is mounted to the disc drive of the VM

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have finished the installation, because the screen you saw is the initial screen before the LiveCD starts. It allows to pass additional option to kernel. After a moment the booting process continues.

Comment: i also believed so and waited, but nothing happened.