# 18.04.4 Ubuntu won't launch in Virtual Box 6.1

Tags: virtualbox, mountpoint

I am taking a Cyber Security class at the local college and am a little experienced in IT.  I have loaded Ubuntu 18.04.4 into Virtualbox 6.1 on a Windows 10 HP laptop.  The HP has a i7 7500u processor and running 16 GB of memory.

My PC's drive says there's no space in the 1.98 GB DVD drive chosen. I think I am unable to mount the drive.  Here is what is in the error message:

> VISO: Cowardly refuses to create empty ISO image (VERR_NO_DATA).

I have a lab in this class and am stuck.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: "2020" is dangerously similar to version 20.04, the next version of Ubuntu, AKA "Ubuntu +1", I removed references to it because Ubuntu+1 bugs are off topic here, and I did not want folks to ignore your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to create the drive for the VM inside of the  installation iso for Ubuntu.

Please see this answer for VERY in-depth steps on the installation process. https://askubuntu.com/a/153098/452485

Despite the age of the answer the steps are still accurate.

The problem is that you need to create the Virtual Disk for the VM to run on as part of the creation process before you install Ubuntu from the iso.

Comment: The link helped me out, i finally got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I was able to help! If this answer answered your question you can mark your question as answered by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.