# Virtual Box Will Not Run Yet

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running Windows 10 and have 32 GB of RAM, an internal hard disk and an external disk with a total of almost 3 TB free.

I have downloaded the latest VirtualBox and Ubuntu and have run the program to create the bootable stick on my `F:` drive, which shows this:

```
Directory: F:\

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        7/24/2020   7:47 PM                LOCALE
-a----        7/24/2020   7:47 PM             96 AUTOEXEC.BAT
-a----        7/24/2020   7:47 PM            232 autorun.inf
-a----        7/24/2020   7:47 PM          34494 autorun.ico
```

BUT, when I try to start up VirtualBox I get this error:

```
Fatal Message:  No Boot-able Medium Found! System Halted
```

I've looked in all VirtualBox menus, but I don't know what to do. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't think that VirtualBox can boot from a USB drive. At least it has been like that tor a long time. But you can connect directly to the iso file when it is stored in the host computer - In the settings of the virtual machine you connect to it as a virtual CD/DVD drive.

Comment: Also see [this guide here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox). If you have any further questions please [edit] this into your question.

Comment: According to this we can run run Ubutu off of a stick drive with Virtual Box:  https://www.lifewire.com/install-ubuntu-linux-windows-10-steps-2202108  The problem is that Virtual Box has not connected the stick drive and the software code in it as I have above.

Comment: Takkat:  Your suggestion is for an answer that is 8 years old.  The web page I gave in he precious reply comment is dated this year, 2020.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? What does a "bootable stick" have to do with virtualbox? Are you trying to run vb on a USB drive?  If not, and if you are trying to create a vb on windoze which runs Ubuntu, you don't need an actual USB. Just download the iso and set it into the 'storage' settings of the vb.  Go to settings/storage in the vb control panel and load the iso into the virtual cd drive.

Comment: According to the instructions for the Virtual Box, I boot from the stick after I've run their "Rufus" program to create the booting operation to start Ubuntu within the Virtual Box.  But, now that I've run Rufus, it did not make some sort of link to the Virtual Box so when, within stating the Virtual Box and then trying to start Ubuntu, it fails with the Fata message I've shown in my first comments.  I've also made a mistake when I wrote this in the first comment:  "an internal hard disk and an external disk with a total of almost 3 GB free"  I have almost 3T free!

Comment: @RetiredGuy: 8 years is a long time but it technically still works absolutely the same today - it is only the designs of the GUI may have changed a bit. Did you try that answer? Where do you get stuck? Please note that you can run a virtual machine stored on USB but you can not boot an installer from USB. Just use the Ubuntu .iso file you have already stored on the hard drive of your computer - no need for Rufus or the like.

Comment: This AM there are at least 2 comments missing fro this question.  You gave me the answer to get the .iso file and I did.  You also provided the picture of the screen and where to insert the .iso file.  I did that but the screen I got to, while it looked exactly like your screen shot, was for the Ubuntu version 20.20 and yours was for, I think 18.4.  On my screen the block to insert the .iso is greyed out.  I don't know what happened to your comment and my reply.  At this point, do I need to UNINSTALL 20.20 and download 18.4 and go through the setup for it and use the .iso file?

Comment: Are there any thoughts to just deleting 20.20 and everything relating to it and getting 184. and it's .iso from https://www.ubuntufree.com/download-ubuntu-18-04-lts/ and putting it in the Virtual Box program?  I am utterly stuck with trying to get 20.20 since I can not insert the .iso into that page as directed to on the comment that is missing from this discussion and as I discussed in my reply comment that is also missing.

Comment: It may work better to solve your problem to start a more discussion-like thread at the [Ubuntu Forum for virtualisation](https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=308). If you do, please put a link to that thread in a comment here, to help me (and other people who visit both AskUbuntu and the Ubuntu Forums) find it.