# Can I run ubuntu 17.10 python behavior on my ubuntu 22.04 (usb stick installation or virtual machin solutions ?)

Tags: virtualbox, 17.10, python3

I would like to run python 3.6 and JS project (2018) on my laptop but I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed and there are a lot of incompatibilities.

As I have many other programs installed, I want to keep my computer running correctly (python and ubuntu 22.04), but would like to boot easily on ubuntu 17.10 to run old projects.

I don't care how to do it, but I cannot reduce my partitions on my laptop (ext4 format).

I tried to install ubuntu on USB drive with percictance, but it wouldn't boot.
Can I install ubuntu on a virtual space, that would keep the packages installed ?
Is there an option for back compatibility in Ubuntu ?

I am open to any solution to easily sought out the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox)

Comment: @karel 17.10 won't work so 18.04 is the oldest they can get and I think that's 3.7.  If they need 3.6, they should do an 18.04 VM and then install the older Python 3.6 into userspace with something like pyenv (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) or such

Comment: @ThomasWard, Why won't 17.10 work in a virtual machine? Do you mean that it is impossible to install program packages via apt? But if the user has own programs (for example as tarballs) they should be possible to install. Or do you mean that it is risky to connect to the internet? Or some other reason?

Comment: @sudodus yes, 17.10 is *long* EOL and in old-releases.  It's also **not supported** anymore, here or anywhere.  17.10 is a long-dead release, if they want "support" they need 18.04 at the earliest.  Anything older is EOL or past EoSS and offtopic here.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers. THe main problem is python compatibility. I guess if they did some real retrocompatibility, we wouldn't have to go back in time, but it is insanely complicated to go back to previous python versions, as your conversation highlights.
I will check to use a virtual machin, but to be honest, what i'm looking for is the simplest (the fewest step) to rollback to code that is "only" 6 years old.

By the way, in science 6 years old is not old as experiments are done on code that can be years old as we don't update machines that work to avoid this exact same problem

Comment: Is there a simple way to just "go back in time" as in python code ?

Comment: It is rather simple to create a virtual machine with VirtualBox and to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as well as Ubuntu 17.10 into the virtual machine and test what works for you. It is even possible to install a suitable point release of 16.04 LTS because it can get extended security maintenance, ESM (paid support 5 years extra beyond the standard lifetime 5 years) and that version might do what you need until April 2026.

Comment: DOes a VM keep percistance and packages installed ?
I'll give it a look. Thanks guys for your help