# How to install package without internet connection

Tags: installation, usb-modem

I installed Ubuntu on an old computer.  It only has a modem port, and no LAN port. But since it has USB then I can use the USB mobile dongle to connect to the Internet.  In order to use it, I need to install the package usb_modeswitch . How and where from to download the files needed from from another computer and how can I install them?

Comment: Yes, download it from another computer put it ont usb , and install it on the old computer.

Comment: yes but how to search and where to find and how to install with what commands

Comment: You can also try with Keryx. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/127923/how-can-i-update-ubuntu-offline-without-using-synaptic-or-keryx/181913#181913.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the necessary files downloaded, and copied to the old computer, take a look [at this site](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1578311)

Or 
 You can [click here to download](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/)

Comment: i would like to download from ubuntu server but how to find package and where and what commands to use universaly for any package from ubuntu server to get same result as if it was with internet connection installed.

Comment: click on the file name in the link that I included, to download the file.

Comment: cant do 1st step sudo aptitude install libusb-dev

Comment: Does it give you any messages?

Comment: yes- couse of no network connection it says E: Couldng find package libusb-dev

Comment: You can download it from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+search?text=libusb-dev

Comment: its getting too complicated. from there witch one libusb_0.1.12.orig.tar.gz (380.2 KiB)
libusb_0.1.12-20.debian.tar.gz (257.1 KiB) and how to install. I found aptoncd programm but with it i cant put on cd usb-modeswitch

Answer (score 1):

Try [APTonCD](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/) a tool with a graphical interface which allows you to create one or more CDs or DVDs with all of the packages you've downloaded via APT-GET or APTITUDE, creating a removable repository that you can use on other computers (description from APTonCD project [website](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: with it cant put usb-modeswitch

Comment: @Kangarooo Do you have any error output?

Comment: No just that package isnt selectable to make aptcd

Comment: @Kangarooo With aptcd you mean APTonCD? 

Is it possible to provide more info?

Comment: Open APTonCD and theres no package usb-modeswitch. I have on computer installed it but its not appearing in APTonCD programm for selection

Comment: @Kangarooo is it the only missing package?

Comment: try yourself- not all packages are available in APTonCD for example even Firefox cant be put in APTonCD

Answer (score 0):

Installation files, and instructions can be found [here](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/). It walks you through compiling the source, kind of a pain, but it seems to me to be pretty straight forward. unpack, run make. Hope it helps.