# how export all software upgrade links (.deb) in text file by terminal

Tags: apt

update Ubuntu by usual way and slow internet is problem for me.

Is there a way into terminal, get all link files that is going to be updated  (eg, the address for Firefox http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_19.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.1_i386.deb)  Into a text file? I want to get these files with download manager (eg downthemall) and then manually enter the path /var/cache/apt/archives placed and upgrade it?

Sorry for unclear whether written, this text was translated by Google Translate.

Comment: Check advice given here: http://askubuntu.com/q/127923/58950. Personally, I use `keryx` regularly. See http://askubuntu.com/a/181913/58950

Comment: Furthermore, although this is not a duplicate, part of the answers to this other question: http://askubuntu.com/q/974/58950, are probably similar to what you'll get here.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `--print-uris` parameter:

```
sudo apt-get -y --print-uris upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  m4
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 250 kB of archives.
After this operation, 39.9 kB disk space will be freed.
'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/m4/m4_1.4.17-2_i386.deb' m4_1.4.17-2_i386.deb 249782 MD5Sum:d0611ffe92bb0d666492333f3c652b40
```

you can make it more quiet:

```
sudo apt-get -qqq -y --print-uris upgrade
'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/m4/m4_1.4.17-2_i386.deb' m4_1.4.17-2_i386.deb 249782 MD5Sum:d0611ffe92bb0d666492333f3c652b40
```

Then redirect the output using stdout redirections:

```
➜  ~  sudo apt-get -qqq -y --print-uris upgrade > upgrade
➜  ~  cat upgrade 
'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/m4/m4_1.4.17-2_i386.deb' m4_1.4.17-2_i386.deb 249782 MD5Sum:d0611ffe92bb0d666492333f3c652b40
```

I would recommend to do `sudo apt-get clean` to prevent that apt-get doesn't print the uris of previous downloaded packages.

Comment: Damnit, I just was writing all that. Great answer !