# How to create a profile in keryx for an offline machine?

Tags: installation, updates, keryx

I have installed `keryx`. When I ran `keryx` in my Windows 7, I didn't find any premade profile for my Ubuntu 13.04. So I have to create a new profile in `keryx` but I don't know how to do that. Please help to create a new profile for Ubuntu 13.04.

Another problem is that when I tried to run the file `keryx.py` in Ubuntu 13.04 using the terminal, it tells to check whether another `keryx` file is running or not.

Answer (score 0):

Steps 3 to 5 of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/181913/58950) tell you how to create a profile of your Ubuntu.

To check if there is another instance of `keryx` running, from a terminal:

```
ps -A | grep 'keryx'
```

That, I imagine, would work if you installed `keryx` from the Software Center (Is it even there?). If you downloaded the package and are running it from the command line, you would have to find the instances of `python` running:

```
ps -A | grep 'python'
```