# Keryx - Installing Applications From Hard Drive

Tags: keryx

How can I use Keryx to download applications not found in Synaptic Repositories or which I have on my hard drive?

Keryx v0.92.4 (Portable),
Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/a/181913/202806.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Gdebi` to install applications that are on the hard drive.
To install gdebi, open a terminal via dash and type.

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Now back to keryx, you can just add required repository to your system by typing following in the terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository {your ppa repository here}
```

Then the repository will be available in keryx as well.

To know which PPA you actually need to add,you can visit the homepage or launchpad page of the application. There you will find the PPA repository address.

To use `gdebi`, **right click** on any one/multiple **.deb** package/s and select **"open with gdebi"**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Gdebi is already installed & I installed Launchpad PPI etc. some time ago but have no idea where they went or how to use them. How do I know which Repositories have the software I want? in this case Litecoin-QT, I have done some research on PPI's but remain baffled. ---- Litecoin-QT is installed on my online Ubuntu PC & I want to install it on an offline Ubuntu Netbook with Keryx on a USB stick. What I really need is a walk-through.

Comment: Correction: I meant PPA

Comment: Turns out Litecoin can be installed by dropping the application folder into my Home folder & linking the executable file to the Ubuntu application menu.