# Workaround to Hash sum mismatch in apt-get update behind firewall

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit virtual machine within a company network which obviously has firewalls. When I try to run sudo apt-get update or sudo apt-get update --fix-missing I get this error:

(Assume archive.ubuntu.com before ever _ubuntu)

```
W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_source_Sources Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial
/_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch /ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Index

W: Failed to fetch /ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Index

W: Failed to fetch /ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_i18n_Index

W: Failed to fetch /ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Index

W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial
/_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_restricted_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried removing `/var/lib/apt/lists` as mentioned in other posts and it does not work. The actual problem is that the company firewall is corrupting the download traffic which gives the hash sum mismatch. This is a known issue as seen here as well:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116641/how-do-you-fix-apt-get-update-hash-sum-mismatch

So, is there any work around to update packages for me and many Ubuntu users behind company firewalls?

Answer (score 1):

I think your options are to:

1. Update from another location, off line. See [How can I update Ubuntu offline without using Synaptic or Keryx?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127923/how-can-i-update-ubuntu-offline-without-using-synaptic-or-keryx)
2. Talk to your sysadmin and have them explore a solution to the firewall.

Comment: I think the question is about online update using apt-get, so the answer is completely irrelavant

Comment: @rancho - you are leaving a comment on what appears to be a duplicate question, abandoned (we have not heard from the OP), and the question is almost 2 years old ? What is the point? If you have a question feel free to ask one.

Answer (score 0):

In case above solution won't work try this one below:

Remove the existing trusted GPG key from the folder `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`

Then run the command:
`sudo apt-key update`

Then try to run: `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: I have nothing in that folder.  I do though have `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` and a `/etc/apt/~trusted.gpg`.

Comment: Why should one remove trusted gpgs?

Comment: @rancho - you are leaving a comment on what appears to be a duplicate question, abandoned (we have not heard from the OP), and the question is almost 2 years old ? What is the point? If you have a question feel free to ask one.