# How do I download a package AND all of its dependencies for offline use later?

Tags: apt, system-installation, dependencies, downloads

I understand how to only download a package with:

```
apt-get download blah
```

...but how do I download all of its dependencies easily as well for an offline install later? Specifically I'll be placing all of this in a custom ISO to be installed at system install/setup without internet.

Comment: Also, check out [How can I update Ubuntu offline without using Synaptic or Keryx?](http://askubuntu.com/q/127923/58950)