# Linux counterpart to Microsoft WSUS [xUbuntu 16.04 Server]

Tags: networking, server, updates, xubuntu, cron

I was wondering if there is a way to configure on of your Ubuntu servers so it will download all the necessary security updates for your OS and your packages on it's own (via cron-job) in some kind of local repository, where other Ubuntu servers in your network **without** internet access can load their updates from?

I can do the part with the cron-job on my own, that's not the problem.
What I don't find, is a tutorial to configure your server as an equivalent to WSUS for Linux.
Is there a way like adding a repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list` ?

Thank you for your help!

-Metadata

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/974/367990 or http://askubuntu.com/q/127923/367990

Comment: I've noticed Amazon does exactly what you are mentioning for their EC2 Ubuntu instances.

Answer (score -1):

It would be difficult to provide support for the myriad of problems that comes with Ubuntu each update. You can use [Cubic](https://launchpad.net/cubic) to preload your own ISO. It allows you to use a terminal the same way you would on a regular install as well as strip it down to make it smaller. I recommend running it within a VM because `chroot` can affect the host system.