# The Package System Is Broken

Tags: 12.04, software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [package system broken, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118749/package-system-broken-how-to-fix)

every time when I'm trying to remove \ install a program or when I'm trying to update the Ubuntu, suddenly an error window opens and it says: The Package System Is Broken.

When I'm try to update Ubuntu, it says the same problem, so I pressed "details" and that's what it says:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies

libdbusmenu-qt2:i386: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.1.3) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is installed
                      Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed
                      Depends: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.6.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                      Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                      Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                      Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed
libqt4-dbus:i386: Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                  Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
libqt4-declarative:i386: Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                         Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                         Depends: libqt4-sql (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                         Depends: libqt4-xmlpatterns (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                         Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                         Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
libqt4-network:i386: Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                     Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
libqt4-script:i386: Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                    Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
libqt4-sql-mysql:i386: Depends: libqt4-sql (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                       Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
libqt4-sql:i386: Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
libqt4-xml:i386: Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386: Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                         Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
libqtgui4:i386: Depends: libqt4-declarative (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
skype-bin:i386: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed
                Depends: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                Depends: libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.6.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.6.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
                Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed
sni-qt:i386: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is installed
             Depends: libdbusmenu-qt2 (>= 0.3.5) but 0.9.2-0ubuntu1 is installed
             Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed
             Depends: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.6.1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
             Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.3-1ubuntu3~) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
             Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.7.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
             Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed
```

Please help me fix this, I can't install \ remove any program and I also can't install updates...