# trying to install libjpeg8 seems to prevent apt-get upgrade

Tags: installation, apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

I'm trying for quite some time to solve an irritating problem.
I'm getting a "hole in the bucket" experience:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for olav: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjpeg8 : Breaks: libjpeg8:i386 (!= 8d-1) but 8c-2ubuntu7 is installed
 libjpeg8:i386 : Breaks: libjpeg8 (!= 8c-2ubuntu7) but 8d-1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

but if i try using -f, this is what appears on the screen:

```
sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libjpeg-turbo8:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libjpeg8:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libjpeg8:i386
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 519 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/132 kB of archives.
After this operation, 258 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
(Reading database ... 482927 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libjpeg8:i386 8c-2ubuntu7 (using .../libjpeg8_8d-1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libjpeg8:i386 ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8', which is also in package libjpeg-turbo8:i386 1.2.1-0ubuntu2
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried all kinds of lines like:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get dist install
sudo apt-get remove
```

and so on

those commands i found on different sites where i was looking for a solution
who can help to fix this?

Comment: Partly solved! Synaptic did the tric. Watch: http://askubuntu.com/questions/195882/the-package-system-is-broken