# How to run g++-4.7 installed in the machine using g++ command?

Tags: package-management, gnome-terminal, g++

I am using Ubuntu 13.10(Saucy). I installed g++-4.7 in my machine. But when I tried to run g++ or tried to check the version it is showing that the package is not installed.

```
$ g++ --version
The program 'g++' can be found in the following packages:
 * g++
 * pentium-builder
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

`sudo apt-get install g++` or `sudo apt-get install g++-4.8` is not successful in my machine because of some broken packages which I couldn't resolve.

Please help me to use g++ with 4.7 version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you instead edit your other question. http://askubuntu.com/q/391070/169736 Also, you don't have g++ installed.

Comment: You probably don't have it installed, otherwise you would get something like [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6578293/). But try `gcc --version` anyway. It may be available from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/g++/) as well.

Comment: @Braiam - What modification do you want in the question askubuntu.com/q/391070/169736 ? I asked you about that there and you didn't reply. Please see that this is completely different question. This is about having got g++-4.7 installed and asking whether there is any provision to run it using g++ command.

Comment: If that's what appears when you type `g++` in a terminal obviously **you don't have the binary installed.** And there's a edit button in each post. What you left me in comments should be **in your question**, not in a comment.

Comment: try
    sudo apt-get update.maybe this helps and then try installing. maybe that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command will help to use g++-4.7 as g++.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.7 /usr/bin/g++
```

This is what I was asking for. In synaptic you can see that g++ is having version 4.8.1. By using the above command you will be able to use g++-4.7 with g++ command in your machine.