# Getting error running sudo apt-get -f install

Tags: apt, package-management

```
E: Waited for /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true but it wasn't there
E: Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true
```

I know this question has been asked before but the answer given returns an error. 
Ubuntu version 10.04.3

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo 'DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-pr econfigure --apt || true";};' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf" 
econfigure: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: true;};' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf: not found
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Package system is broken. How to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/118749/package-system-is-broken-how-to-fix-it)

Comment: @Kaobear: No, this question isn't about a broken package system.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
echo 'DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf
```

instead of

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-pr econfigure --apt || true";};' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf"
```