# Problem with broken package system

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-center, package-management

Yesterday I found that the Code::Blocks 13.12 on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is broken, when I clicked the icon, it reacted nothing, so I tried to reinstall.

I tried to use the instructions from codeblocks' official website to install codeblocks 
http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_Code::Blocks_nightly_build_on_Ubuntu 
but it failed

```
yuyue@ThinkPad:~/Downloads/debian-stable/amd64$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
    dpkg-deb: error: `amd64.deb' is not a debian format archive
    dpkg: error processing amd64.deb (--install):
     subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
    Selecting previously unselected package codeblocks.
    (Reading database ... 299683 files and directories currently installed.)
    Unpacking codeblocks (from codeblocks_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Preparing to replace codeblocks-common 13.12-1 (using codeblocks-common_13.12-1_all.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement codeblocks-common ...
    Selecting previously unselected package codeblocks-contrib.
    Unpacking codeblocks-contrib (from codeblocks-contrib_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Preparing to replace codeblocks-contrib-common 13.12-1 (using codeblocks-contrib-common_13.12-1_all.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement codeblocks-contrib-common ...
    Selecting previously unselected package codeblocks-contrib-dbg.
    Unpacking codeblocks-contrib-dbg (from codeblocks-contrib-dbg_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package codeblocks-dbg.
    Unpacking codeblocks-dbg (from codeblocks-dbg_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Preparing to replace codeblocks-dev 13.12-1 (using codeblocks-dev_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement codeblocks-dev ...
    Preparing to replace codeblocks-headers 13.12-1 (using codeblocks-headers_13.12-1_all.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement codeblocks-headers ...
    Preparing to replace codeblocks-libwxcontrib0 13.12-1 (using codeblocks-libwxcontrib0_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement codeblocks-libwxcontrib0 ...
    Preparing to replace codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev 13.12-1 (using codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev ...
    Preparing to replace codeblocks-wxcontrib-headers 13.12-1 (using codeblocks-wxcontrib-headers_13.12-1_all.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement codeblocks-wxcontrib-headers ...
    Preparing to replace libcodeblocks0 13.12-1 (using libcodeblocks0_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement libcodeblocks0 ...
    Preparing to replace libwxsmithlib0 13.12-1 (using libwxsmithlib0_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement libwxsmithlib0 ...
    Preparing to replace libwxsmithlib0-dev 13.12-1 (using libwxsmithlib0-dev_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement libwxsmithlib0-dev ...
    Preparing to replace wxsmith-dev 13.12-1 (using wxsmith-dev_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement wxsmith-dev ...
    Preparing to replace wxsmith-headers 13.12-1 (using wxsmith-headers_13.12-1_all.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement wxsmith-headers ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of codeblocks:
     codeblocks depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0); however:
      Version of libfontconfig1 on system is 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1.
    dpkg: error processing codeblocks (--install):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Setting up codeblocks-common (13.12-1) ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of codeblocks-contrib:
     codeblocks-contrib depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0); however:
      Version of libfontconfig1 on system is 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1.
     codeblocks-contrib depends on libgamin0; however:
      Package libgamin0 is not installed.
     codeblocks-contrib depends on codeblocks (= 13.12-1); however:
      Package codeblocks is not configured yet.
    dpkg: error processing codeblocks-contrib (--install):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Setting up codeblocks-contrib-common (13.12-1) ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of codeblocks-contrib-dbg:
     codeblocks-contrib-dbg depends on codeblocks-contrib (= 13.12-1); however:
      Package codeblocks-contrib is not configured yet.
    dpkg: error processing codeblocks-contrib-dbg (--install):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of codeblocks-dbg:
     codeblocks-dbg depends on codeblocks (= 13.12-1); however:
      Package codeblocks is not configured yet.
    dpkg: error processing codeblocks-dbg (--install):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Setting up codeblocks-libwxcontrib0 (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up codeblocks-wxcontrib-headers (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up libcodeblocks0 (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up libwxsmithlib0 (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up wxsmith-dev (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up wxsmith-headers (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up libwxsmithlib0-dev (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up codeblocks-dev (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up codeblocks-headers (13.12-1) ...
    Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
    Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
    Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
    Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
    Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
    Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
    Processing triggers for man-db ...
    Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
    ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     amd64.deb
     codeblocks
     codeblocks-contrib
     codeblocks-contrib-dbg
     codeblocks-dbg
```

then I tried this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pasgui/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

and after this I installed Code::Blocks 13.12 successfully, but when I opened it I found that I can't build or run any files(seemed to have problem with plugins)

```
Errors were encountered while processing: codeblocks codeblocks-contrib codeblocks-dbg codeblocks-contrib-dbg E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and then I found my package system was broken...
I don't have Synaptic Package Manager on my computer, 
I followed this instruction(from [Package system is broken. How to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118749/package-system-is-broken-how-to-fix-it))

> After you get that error, try sudo apt-get -f install to force an
>   install of the files that didn't get loaded because of the error.
>
> Then try sudo apt-get update again, sudo apt-get -f install back and
>   forth until only the package that has the error is left.
>
> sudo dpkg --configure -a
>
> and clean the cache
>
> sudo apt-get clean

it looks like that nothing effective was done.
I opened Ubuntu Software Center, and it notified me to download something to repair the package system, I did it, and in the end I found my package system is still broken...

Is there anyone who have a good idea about what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

From the `dpkg` output, it looks like you need to upgrade `libfontconfig1` and install `libgamin0`. The `codeblocks` packages cannot install until you do this.

For the newer version of `libfontconfig1`, you either need to upgrade Ubuntu (12.10 or newer) or find a PPA with a newer version for 12.04.

For `libgamin0`, it should be available to install. Make sure the `universe` repository is enabled (in Synaptic or Software Settings).