# Update Error (using apt-get install -f)?

Tags: 12.04, apt, update-manager

So I tried updating my system, to find this pop-up error upon attempt,

```
The package system is broken

Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them,
since they are a common source of problems. Furthermore run the
following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
```

I ran the command under **sudo** in the command prompt, to find this issue,

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done Correcting dependencies... Done The
following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
required:   nvidia-settings-updates libudev0:i386 Use 'apt-get
autoremove' to remove them. The following extra packages will be
installed:   tor Suggested packages:   mixmaster xul-ext-torbutton
socat tor-arm apparmor-utils The following NEW packages will be
installed:   tor 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 243
not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/1,097
kB of archives. After this operation, 2,571 kB of additional disk
space will be used. Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y (Reading database
... 388724 files and directories currently installed.) Unpacking tor
(from .../tor_0.2.4.21-1~precise+1_amd64.deb) ... dpkg: error
processing /var/cache/apt/archives/tor_0.2.4.21-1~precise+1_amd64.deb
(--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/tor', which is also in
package tor-browser 2.3.25-12 dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was
killed by signal (Broken pipe) Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing: 
/var/cache/apt/archives/tor_0.2.4.21-1~precise+1_amd64.deb E:
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What can I do to fix this error and get my update underway?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/118749/package-system-is-broken-how-to-fix-it

Answer (score 1):

1. After you get that error, try sudo apt-get -f install to force an

install of the files that didn't get loaded because of the error.

Then try sudo apt-get update again, sudo apt-get -f install back and
forth until only the package that has the error is left.

> ```
> sudo dpkg --configure -a
>
> and clean the cache
>
> sudo apt-get clean
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `tor-browser` package and fix the dependencies.

```
sudo dpkg -P tor-browser
sudo apt-get install -f
```