# apt-get, unmet dependencies, ... "but it is not going to be installed"

Tags: apt

```
$ apt-get install -f -o 'Dpkg::Options::=--force-confmiss --force-all --force-confnew --overwrite-conffiles' --reinstall at-spi2-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-workspace-bin : Depends: qdbus but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-dbus : Depends: qdbus (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I don't quite understand "but it is not going to be installed". Why doesn't it install it then?

`apt-get -f install` does not help, it does nothing:

```
$ apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: You could try to find out why qdbus is not being installed by installing it yourself: `sudo apt-get install qdbus`.

Comment: @Jos: I did that. Now it works. However, that doesn't really answer my question or what the problem was.

Comment: I suppose it was the combination of options in your original apt-get command that prevented apt from installing additional dependencies.

Comment: Here it was that I missed `main` and only had `deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily universe multiverse` in addition to trusty. Then, apt wanted to install a package from universe, which depended on versions available in wily/main only and thus could not be installed.

Comment: Try adding the missing package to the install command: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall at-spi2-core qdbus libqt4-dbus`

Comment: It is possible that you are trying to install a version of a package that conflicts with other things on your system.  Here is an example: try to install a 32 version of virtualbox on a 64 bit system.  You system figures out that all the 32 bit dependencies would not be a good idea.

Answer (score 37):

This worked for me.

```
$ sudo apt-get install <missing-package-1> <missing-package-2> ...
```

I don't know why this is necessary, but manually installing the problematic packages worked.

After installing the first round of unmet dependencies, another one popped up, but I repeated the process and it sorted itself out after two cycles.

Comment: Wow, it really is this simple... It makes me wonder why it wouldn't install in the first place?

Comment: This helped me too, but had to run twice second time with reverse order of package names. Not sure if reversing order was necessary.

Comment: Does not work every time. Older packages that were removed will never install this way. Example `Depends: iptables-dev but it is not installable`.

Comment: as the error says, the package is not installable, so it does not help...

Answer (score 22):

As [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/118749) also didn't help, I found on [this LinuxQuestions thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/help-with-apt-get-dependency-error-depends-but-is-not-going-to-be-installed-749121/) a hint that helped me:

Do you have a mixed `/etc/apt/sources.list`? It appears that you're trying to install one package from a newer repository but that it doesn't have access to a repository with the newer dependencies.

Comment: A mixed sources file, or maybe one with only a single repository but that has missing packages

Comment: I had the same problem - my `sources.list` had only the `main` repository and the dependency was somewhere else (`universe`, `restricted`, ...). The error message is very misleading.

Comment: Yes, this is a possible reason. For example, ubuntu 20.04 with ubuntu 16.04 (xenial)'s sources.list, would make `apt install xxx` report similar problem.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this issue and solved it by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then when I ran the original "apt-get install" command succeeded.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing above worked for me but following procedure saved me

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

this will list the broken packages and

```
sudo dpkg -r librrd4
```

{librrd4 and libpng12 were my broken pakages
solved the problem

Comment: Thank god. `dpkg -r` saved me. Stupid apt

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue while installing **Guake**; it showed `unmet dependencies` with Python. Even trying to reinstall python using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python` did nothing.

Finally,

Step-1: I had to remove and install python again using:

**Note: Uninstalling `python` leads to removing many other dependencies which may break the installed Ubuntu, so be careful while uninstalling `python`**

`sudo apt-get purge python`

`sudo apt-get install python`

Step-2: Install the original package (in my case it was guake)

`sudo apt-get install guake`

This installed all necessary dependencies.

**Try the same procedure w/ your packages and it should work for you too.**

Comment: Removing Python, even only temporarily, is a bad idea as it will likely remove lots of depending packages with it and it is needed to run many important system commands.

Comment: I was aware of this possibility but i wasn't able to solve my issue otherwise....searched a lot but could not find a working way....as of now my ubuntu has not broken ..... waiting for it in future ;) ...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while trying to install another package. Using `aptitude` instead of `apt-get` helped solve the issue for me.
Refer this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1379008/413845

Comment: In my case there was some impossible package situation, and aptitude provided an update plan to get around the problem. Definitely try this solution if you encounter this issue, otherwise you'll have to figure out the solution manually, as evidenced by the myriad of answers to this question

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with `cups-filters` on raspberrypi caused by realvnc-vnc-server. It was due to foomatic-filters being deprecated. I couldn't install or uninstall anything so what worked for me was to delete the apt cache for cups-filters.

`sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/cups-filters*`

Then the install worked as suggested by @funroll

`sudo apt install cups cup-filters`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it needed the version of the package from `focal`, but it wanted to install the version from `focal-updates`. On theory it can be fixed by running `apt-install pkg_name_here=older_specific_version_here`. In my specific case that wasn't acceptable because i had many packages depending on the newer version of one of the nested dependencies which it wanted to remove along the downgrade, so i said no.

Answer (score 0):

Get your broken/missing dependencies using

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Once you have it, try installing them manually.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, remember to run `sudo apt update` before running things like `apt-get install -f` or `sudo apt --fix-missing install`, otherwise you might get an error because apt cannot find the newest packages which are required.