# build-dep monodevelop fails: libmono-cecil-cil-dev is not going to be installed

Tags: apt, 16.04, compiling, monodevelop

I have run: `sudo apt-get build-dep monodevelop` but it returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 builddeps:monodevelop : Depends: libmono-cecil-cil-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please reference [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564282/apt-get-unmet-dependencies-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed) to give you some context to my answer.

Run `$ sudo apt-get install libmono-cecil-cil-dev`.

I don't know why this is necessary, but manually installing the problematic package should get your install of `monodevelop` to work.

It is possible that after installing the unmet dependency `libmono-cecil-cil-dev`, other unmet dependencies might pop up, but repeating the process with the new unmet dependencies should finally get you to the point of being able to install `monodevelop`.

Comment: I should have probably mentioned I had tried that. This recursive method gets me up to `$ sudo apt-get install libmono-cecil-cil-dev libmono-cecil-cil libmono-cecil-private-cil`: which gives the error: http://paste2.org/NwGBU6gj.