# Cannot install python venv on Ubuntu 20.04 after upgrading from Bionic

Tags: python3

After a system update to Ubuntu 20.04, I've had various issues with python. The current problem is that I cannot create a virtual environment:

`python3 -m venv env`

```
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/XXX/my-project/env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

To find out more about why it is failing I ran
`./env/bin/python3 -Im ensurepip --upgrade --default-pip`:

```
/env/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'ensurepip.__main__' (ImportError: cannot import name '_bundled' from partially initialized module 'ensurepip' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3.9/ensurepip/__init__.py))
```

Of course I tried the suggested step with `sudo apt-get install python3-venv`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-venv : Depends: python3.8-venv (>= 3.8.2-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`lsb_release -a` output:

> Description:  Ubuntu 20.04.1
>
> LTS Release:  20.04
>
> Codename: focal

`whereis python` output:

`python: /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.9 /usr/lib/python3.8 /etc/python3.6 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python3.9 /etc/python3.8 /etc/python /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.9 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.6 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/include/python3.8 /usr/share/python`

`/etc/apt/sources.list` only contains *focal* software sources.

also ran

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade
```

removed python3.9, `sudo apt install python3.8-venv` fails with the same error

> python3.8-venv : Depends: python3.8 (= 3.8.5-1~20.04) but 3.8.6-1+bionic1 is to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

`dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` returns empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections` doesn't find any held packages but I'll try the other suggestions

Comment: You seem to have python3.9 installed which is not installed by default on 20.04. The `python-venv` package may be having issues getting installed because of that. (just speculating here)

Comment: installing python 3.9 was my first attempt to solve the problem :)

Comment: How did you install 3.9? It might have messed with the dependancies. Can you try removing it and try the `apt install python3-venv` again? I just tried your command and I got the same error, but installing `python3-venv` fixed it for me.

Comment: Does this help with the dependency problem? https://askubuntu.com/a/606896/ Even if it does, I still recommend making sure that the python3.9 installation didn't mess up your system. You have changed the default environment for Ubuntu to use python3.9 by default. It may cause similar issues later with other packages if that was the case.

Comment: I've removed python 3.9. `./env/bin/python3 -Im ensurepip --upgrade --default-pip` now failes with `No module named ensurepip`.

Comment: AskUbuntu is not a threaded help forum that can wind from topic to topic (ubuntuforums.org is). AskUbuntu is a Question/Answer site. This is your third independent question trying to squeeze into a single question, which makes it hard for volunteers here to answer usefully. Remember that questions and answers should help future users, too.

Answer (score 10):

Looking at the info you provided, your problem might be due to the python3.9 installation.

In Ubuntu 20.04, the default python version is 3.8. So other packages that depend on python should be expecting python3.8.

However, in your system, this default was changed to Python 3.9 as the attempt to create a new venv ended up with a Python 3.9 environment as observed in the outputs.

As your original error mentions, you need to install the `python3-venv` package using `apt`. But since python3.9 was installed as well, I believe `apt` isn't able to figure out anymore what to install. So explicitly mentioning the full version may solve your problem.

```bsh
sudo apt install python3.8-venv
```

*ref: [apt-get, unmet dependencies, ... "but it is not going to be installed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564282/apt-get-unmet-dependencies-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed/606896#606896.)*

After that is done, you need to create a venv by also explicitly passing the full python version

```bsh
python3.8 -m venv env
```

---

If your intention is to use Python 3.9, and as long as it was installed with `apt`, you can fix it by installing `python3.9-venv` instead of `python3.8-venv`

```bsh
sudo apt install python3.9-venv
```

ps. You will need to create a new virtual environment again after installing the apt package. The previous one will stay broken.

Comment: `sudo apt install python3.8-venv` throws the same error: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.8-venv : Depends: python3.8 (= 3.8.5-1~20.04) but 3.8.6-1+bionic1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` returns empty

Comment: @kosmičák Try running `sudo apt update` then run the install command.

Comment: You have an extra PPA that is trying to install a newer version of python3.8. You will need to disable that as it's causing this conflict

Answer (score 1):

Using `aptitude` instead of `apt-get` fixed it for me.

1. Install aptitude `sudo apt-get install aptitude`
2. Now try installing `python3.8-venv` with aptitude and follow the steps as shown in the below screenshot
   [image]

Once the above steps were completed, `python3 -m venv env` command worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a simmilar problem. I can't install `python3.8-venv` package, because of a newer version of `python3.8` package (with ~20.04 postfix). It turned out that I hadn't **focal-security** source in my source.list.

Adding `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main universe` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` fixed the problem.

Comment: After adding ```deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main universe``` in ```/etc/apt/sources.list```, we need to run ```apt update``` and then ```apt upgrade python-pip-whl python3-pip```. It works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04 which was not going away event after `apt update` command. I updated the apt repo url in /etc/apt/sources.list from http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ to http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/. Which resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I had to keep removing various **bionic** python packages:

```bsh
sudo apt remove python3.8
sudo apt remove python3.8-minimal
sudo apt remove libpython3.8-stdlib
sudo apt remove libpython3.8-minimal
```

Whenever it complained about them...

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.8 : Depends: python3.8-minimal (= 3.8.5-1~20.04) but 3.8.6-1+bionic1 is to be installed
             Depends: libpython3.8-stdlib (= 3.8.5-1~20.04) but 3.8.6-1+bionic1 is to be installed
```

... I removed them

...until I could (re)install these:

```bsh
sudo apt install python3.8-minimal
sudo apt install python3.8
sudo apt install python3.8-venv
sudo apt install python3-distutils
```

and I could finally run `python3.8 -m venv env`

So it seems that the upgrade from *Bionic Beaver* to *Focal Fossa* partially left old python packages behind which introduced the incompatibilites.

Comment: -1. removing 3.8 can uninstall ubuntu-desktop, not recommended, be careful doing this

Comment: true, that's what actually happened in my case :) I couldn't boot into X after that, had to reinstall the missing packages from terminal and afterwards everything was working again.